# simplification of the derivative formula of the error function in neural networks

Tags: neural-network

There is a graph that show the error function in a neural network. In short, the purpose moving left or right to go deep by calculating derivative.
I understand the first formula except summation symbol part. What does that mean ? Doesn't  "n" how to be on summation symbol ? Also why is there a summation symbol ? I think error function must be depend on output node's weight ? And How did we get rid of that symbol at the down of the page ?

There is a pic to see the problem.
https://ibb.co/gjsCHkV

Comment: We need more material to answer this question. Where is this taken from? It is very difficult to understand it without knowing what `t_n` and `o_n` is.

Comment: Sorry, it is from book that Make Your Neural Network. Error means (target value) - (output value) in neural networks. t_n means result that should be in node n, and o_n is the real output in node n.
Make Your Neural Network, Page 94